# Super annoying Alt-Tab rendering glitch in MS Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

When I switch to the Word 2007 by Alt-Tab, there is the annoying blue bar covering the text. The blue bar will disappear after re-rendering by pressing PgUp - PgDn, but it is annoying. Any idea how to get rid of it?

I had this exact problem few years ago, and now it appeared again! I am almost sure it wasn't there earlier today and that it hasn't been present for a long time. Not sure about what brought it back and how to get rid of it again. It must be possible somehow.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: The *blue bar* seems to have an arrow button on each end ... and a thumb grip! Hey, it's a scrollbar! What did you have on the left side at an earlier time? Maybe the  box showing different unsaved versions of the document after an earlier abrupt shutdown. Close the document and save if you have unsaved changes. Then open it again to see if it is gone.

Comment: Or maybe you have used something from the `View` - `Show / Hide` items, e.g. `Document map` which is shown on the left, and the scrollbars just remains. Again stop and restart should help.